# Regular expressions php split

Tags: php

I need to split a string like `'7-2014'` into an array `[7],[2014]` in PHP.

For this special case,

```
$arr = preg_split('/-/','7-2014');
```

works fine, but how can I make an expression that splits on any of these characters: `. / \ space`?

Comment: any of these characters - yes, u r right

Comment: The first example in the manual on `preg_split()` would have told you that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
$arr = preg_split('%[-./\\\\ ]%', $subject);
```

This will split along dashes, dots, slashes, backslashes and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to define multiple characters:

```
$arr = preg_split('#[-\\.\\\\\/ ]#','7-2014');
```

Comment: There are three unnecessary backslashes here :)

Comment: Better be safe than sorry O:-)